# AWS Batch Job container_properties is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'v' looking for beginning of value

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, batch-processing

I'm using terraform to create aws batch job definition:

```
resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "test" {
    name = "jobtest"
    type = "container"
    container_properties =<<CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
{
    "image": var.image,
    "memory": 512,
    "vcpus": 1,
    "jobRoleArn": "${aws_iam_role.job_role.arn}"
}
CONTAINER_PROPERTIES
}
```

When I run terraform I get this error:

```
AWS Batch Job container_properties is invalid: Error decoding JSON: invalid character 'v' looking for beginning of value

  on admin/prd/batch.tf line 1, in resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "test":
   1: resource "aws_batch_job_definition" "test" {
```

I don't know what's wrong here. I couldn't find any answers in the other StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Possibly related [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16332)

Comment: @Jamie_D no, please check here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/batch_job_definition.html only json is making trouble here, we don't put commas in terraform after each parameter.

Comment: There are a few coma missing

Comment: Yes, I deleted my comment after I discover that ;)

Comment: @anonjnr I forgot one comma after var.image but it didn't make it any better.

Comment: I just ran into this problem with the JobRoleArn, and I believe the issue in this snippet is that var.image needs to be a string.

Comment: @x3l51 - you saved the day for me, I did everything exactly the same as described, except an extra comma and that took me time to figureout until I read your comment. thanks